# Working in Visual Studio 2008, VB File IO Creation/Opening

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to search for a file in VB.  If it exists I'd like to read it in.  If it doesn't not exist I'd like to create it.  I'm working in Visual Studio 2008.  I was using a Streamreader before, but when I did that I was never getting any sort of error if the file wasn't there, which isn't what I want.  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`File.Open("path", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I feel the following 2 code pieces are the easiest to write and read files respectively:-

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(**FILE LOCATION**, **FILE CONTENTS**, **APPEND OR NOT (BOOLEAN)**)

My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(**FILE LOCATION**)
```

Hope this helps! :D